# MySQL View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause... help to rewrite?

Tags: mysql

I'm building a web app that needs to reference data from a single view.

I know that I can't have a from clause in a sub-query in create or replace view but I was only able to come up with one version of this query that returns the result I need.

After hours of trawling through posts on here I couldn't come up with any solutions for it.
Is there someone with more smarts than I have that can re-fudge this query in such a way that all the data can be returned in a single view?
Here is the query ...

```html
CREATE
OR REPLACE VIEW in_stock_levels AS
SELECT
  *,
  `in_stock` - `maximum_stock` AS levels
FROM(
    SELECT
      stock_levels.id AS id,
      stock_levels.part_number AS part_number,
      stock_levels.minimum_stock AS minimum_stock,
      stock_levels.maximum_stock AS maximum_stock,
      (
        SELECT
          COUNT(*)
        FROM
          automatic_transmission_jobs
        WHERE
          part_number = stock_levels.part_number
          AND test_result != "Not Tested"
          AND status != "pwa"
      ) AS in_stock
    FROM
      stock_levels
  ) AS check_stock
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a JOIN of the two source tables to create your VIEW instead of subqueries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it this way works, I know it's not the most efficient,

```html
CREATE
OR REPLACE VIEW in_stock_levels AS
SELECT
      stock_levels.id AS id,
      stock_levels.part_number AS part_number,
      stock_levels.minimum_stock AS minimum_stock,
      stock_levels.maximum_stock AS maximum_stock,
      (
        SELECT
          COUNT(*)
        FROM
          automatic_transmission_jobs
        WHERE
          part_number = stock_levels.part_number
          AND test_result != "Not Tested"
          AND status != "pwa"
      ) AS in_stock,
      (
        SELECT
          COUNT(*)
        FROM
          automatic_transmission_jobs
        WHERE
          part_number = stock_levels.part_number
          AND test_result != "Not Tested"
          AND status != "pwa"
      ) - stock_levels.maximum_stock AS stock_level
    FROM
      stock_levels
```

Thanks for all your help Ingo :)

Answer (score 0):

Without having more information on your schema, but based on what you posted, the following query should work for your CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW...

```
SELECT
    stock_levels.id,
    stock_levels.part_number,
    stock_levels.minimum_stock,
    stock_levels.maximum_stock,
    COUNT(automatic_transmission_jobs.id) AS in_stock,
    in_stock - maximum_stock AS levels
FROM stock_levels
LEFT OUTER JOIN automatic_transmission_jobs USING (part_number)
WHERE
    automatic_trasmission_jobs.test_result != 'Not Tested'
    AND automatic_trasmission_jobs.status !='pwa'
GROUP BY stock_levels.id;
```

Do you use phpMyAdmin or MySQLWorkbench to design and test your queries?

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try, I'm using phpMyAdmin on the slowest server on earth at the moment.

Comment: I'm just about to try it out, I just got back on site today.  I will post the result :)

Comment: Tested with the following result...    #1054 - Unknown column 'in_stock' in 'field list' I'm guessing it's beacuse this query is creating the 'in_stock' column but its doing the subtraction before it does the count to create the 'in_stock' column?

Comment: I removed the ticks around in_stock and maximum_stock where we are assigning the difference of the two to levels, please try again.

Comment: I'm getting a result with this...   SELECT
  stock_levels.id,
  stock_levels.part_number,
  stock_levels.minimum_stock,
  stock_levels.maximum_stock,
  COUNT(automatic_transmission_jobs.id) AS in_stock,
  'in_stock' - maximum_stock AS levels
FROM
  stock_levels
  LEFT OUTER JOIN automatic_transmission_jobs USING (part_number)
WHERE
  automatic_transmission_jobs.test_result != 'Not Tested'
  AND automatic_transmission_jobs.status != 'pwa'
GROUP BY
  stock_levels.id but the levels column is returning as though in_stock is always 0